# Create a hierarchy between tables following relationship

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am confused with pivot tables, and it's a recurring issue! Say I have put 2 tables in my data model (classes and students):

[tables classes and students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDJD.png)

My model is this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbcAd.png)

I want to build this simple pivot table, displaying under classname, student name (no sum or number, just plain values) like so.

[expected pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Thi.png)

If I do it like that, as proposed by @Cpt.Whale :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkDOy.png)

I get all students under each class like in a cartesian product. I just want to get the students who are associated with the class. If student fname were in class table, I simply would do a hierarchy. I want to do the equivalent of the hierarchy with the 2 tables. It might be obvious, but I cannot do it!

**Update**

I tried again and found a way to do it using `RELATED()` DAX function in a calculated column :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAqP9.png)

I this case, the solution proposed by @Cpt.Whale indeed works correctly :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSnxz.png)

Is there a better and simpler way without using a calculated column,  directly in Pivot Table, with kind of an implicit RELATED funtion ?

Sorry for all screenshots being in French Excel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try and move `fname` to the Rows (Lignes) section and place it under `classname`. Does that give you the view you want?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I did what you proposed in first trial. I realised it wasn't correct, as all students appear under each classname (see last image of my post). I just want the related ones. I thought that it's the purpose of relationships, but strangely enough I'm stuck with this simple question!  I finally did it with `RELATED()` DAX function (see my update), but I guess there would be a better way.

Comment: I found it also works correctly if you have *any* column from the local table in the Values section, like `count of classname` or your calculated column, but never(?) when using foreign columns. Maybe buggy behavior with the internal olap connections? I'm not sure...

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I don't think there there is a bug here, just that I don't understand the way it works and the origin of this 'cross join'.

Answer (score 0):

If data is sorted this way, in Office 365 you could also achieve it using formula:

```
=HSTACK(MAP(classes[classname],LAMBDA(a,IF(COUNTIF(TAKE(classes[classname],1):a,a)-1,"",a))),
        XLOOKUP(Students[studentid],students[studentid],students[fname]))
```

Where you could replace `TAKE(classes[classname],1)` with the first cell ID, like `A3` or if you start in the same row as the table with `classes[@classname]`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have any Microsoft 365 subscription, so no access to `lambda`, not even `hstack` or `map` function, . Anyway a lot too advanced to my Excel level as of now !